# Blazor server app hosted in Windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, blazor-server-side

How can we host a Blazor server application as a Windows service? Using this article as a guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0

We create a minimal example using dotnet version 6.0. First create a blazor server application from template.

`dotnet new blazorserver`

Then add NuGet package for Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices

`dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices`

In `Program.cs`, configure the host to run as a Windows service.

```
//...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

// Configure to run as Windows service
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

var app = builder.Build();
//...
```

Publish the app as an executable.

`dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained false`

Copy contents from /bin/Release/net6.0/win-x64/publish/ folder to server. On the server, cd to the folder with the exe and run the exe from the command line.

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestBlazor> .\blazor-server-as-service.exe
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestBlazor\
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
```

Success.

Configure new windows service.

`New-service -Name "TestBlazorService" -BinaryPathName C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestBlazor\blazor-server-as-service.exe`

Edit the service to use my credentials. Grant log on as service rights. Start the service.

```
PS> start-service TestBlazorService
start-service : Service 'TestBlazorService (TestBlazorService)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot
start service TestBlazorService on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ start-service TestBlazorService
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

From the event log:

```
A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the TestBlazorService service to connect.

The TestBlazorService service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took way longer than I'd like to admit. The blazorserver template created a `WebApplicationBuilder`.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDependencyRepository, DependencyRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

And I was trying to access and configure the `IHostBuilder` member, and then build and use the `WebBuilder`.

```
//...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

// Configure to run as Windows service
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

var app = builder.Build();
```

My understanding of the asp.net host model is not great, but I think I need to create an instance of `IHostBuilder`, configure it to run as a services, and configure the `IWebHostBuilder` within it for all the web related settings. Then actually build the `IHostBuilder` - the thing I configured to run as a service.

I added a `Startup` class to handle the web configuration and changed `Program.cs` to:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>())
    .UseWindowsService()
    .Build()
    .Run();
```

Installed on server. Service successfully starts and runs. Maybe there's a better way. If not, I hope this will help someone else.

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#differences-between-the-aspnet-core-5-and-6-hosting-models) It looks like it is not possible to change the host after the `WebApplicationBuilder` is created. I think the means `UseWindowsService` will not work on the dotnet 6 minimal hosting model.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Install **Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices** from NuGet Package Manager.
Step 2. Add to program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices;
```

Step 3. Change **var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);** to the following code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions()
{
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default,
    Args = args
});
```

Step 4. Add before **var app = builder.Build();** to the following code:

```
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
```

Step 5. Publish the app to folder
Step 6. Run cmd.exe as administrator.
Step 7. Create a Service with the following command:

```
sc create <SERVICE_NAME> binPath="<BIN_PATH>"
```

Example:

```
sc create MySerice binPath="C:\MySolution\MyProject\bin\Release\net7.0\publish\MyProject.exe"
```

Step 8. Start the Service with the following command:

```
net start <SERVICE_NAME>
```

Example:

```
net start MySerice
```

Comment: In order to manage the worker service from the Blazor server application, should the worker service be in the Blazor server project?